# QuickSort Running time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

So, I am learning about QuickSort and have a slight confusion about running times. There are three types of input: increasing order, decreasing order and random order. If we choose the pivot from the first position of the subarray (input), I know that sorting the input in increasing order or decreasing order takes O(n^2). Will sorting the random order input take O(nlogn) or still take same O(n^2) time?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the confusion. I edited the question again, I meant sorting the three different types of inputs.

Comment: On random input it will take "expected O(n log n) time." but will still be O(n^2) worst case time.

Comment: refer [quicksort](https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/10analysis/) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Worst case time complexity still remains as O(N^2).

Therefore, many of the Quicksort variations used now-a-days, randomise the input before sorting to avoid the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add some helper function to selected pivot you will always risk the worst case, using median-of-medians to select pivots solves the that problem but increases absolute total run time.

Therefor nearly all quicksort's are hybrids of some kind, using median-of-medians or a fall-back to heap-sort, there might be other methods that I'm not aware of.